# I don’t understand why if constexpr works like that

Tags: c++

The following code

```
#include <string>

void set_string(std::string) {
}

int main() {
    if constexpr (false) {set_string(true);}
}
```

does not compile with an error

```
error: no matching function for call to 'set_string'

        if constexpr (false) {set_string(true);}

                              ^~~~~~~~~~

<source>:3:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'bool' to 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') for 1st argument
```

But `set_string(true)` is  discarded statement and should  be dropped. I'm right?

Comment: Usually the condition must depend on some template parameter. I'd look for a dup, but I'm on mobile

Comment: If you really think about it, there is no reason to have `if constexpr (false)`.  You know, right then and there that the branch will never be called, so you can just not write it.  It's when you get into templates, where the compiler has to deduce the value of the condition, where constexpr if makes sense.

Comment: Outside a template, a discarded statement is fully checked. if constexpr is not a substitute for the #if preprocessing directive.

Comment: @NathanOliver: One possible reason might be to replace some pre-processor condition. To have something like `if constexpr (Windows)` instead of `#ifdef __WIN32`.

Comment: @Jarod42 That wasn't what it was designed for though.  We already have have the preprocessor.  What we did not have was an easy way to do different things based on the different types passed to a template function.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Some people expect to get rid of MACRO and pre-processor stuff with future of C++. ((variadic) template, `constexpr`, `std::source_location`, ...,  go in that direction (even if it was not necessary their primary goal)).

Comment: And without that, there are still stuff to handle implementation specific stuff as `if constexpr (sizeof (int) == 4)`.